# Python Pandas function which computes over previous row and current row

Tags: python, pandas

[image: 'EXCEL SHEET EXAMPLE']

Give a DataFrame I would like to transform to another, where the transform function operates on previous row and current row.
In the Given example,

`RowID =1 is copied as is,`

but RowID 2 onward,

```
Current Cell = Max(CurrentCell, Previous Cell * 0.9999 )
H4 <= MAX(B4, H3*0.9999)
where,
B4  = original value, 
H3  = the previous row **'After Transformation'**
```

[image]

Comment: Possibly [pandas rolling()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) function?

Comment: Could you please provide a working example ?

Answer (score 2):

Here is on way , create you own function with `cumsum` and `cumcount` , then `update` the columns

```
def yourfun(s):
    s.update(s.mask(s==0).ffill()-s.groupby(s.mask(s==0).eq(1).cumsum()).cumcount()*0.0001)
    return s
df.apply(yourfun)
Out[291]: 
        1       2       3       4
0  0.0000  0.0000  1.0000  0.0000
1  0.0000  1.0000  0.9999  1.0000
2  0.0000  0.9999  0.9998  0.9999
3  1.0000  0.9998  0.9997  1.0000
4  0.9999  1.0000  1.0000  0.9999
5  0.9998  0.9999  0.9999  0.9998
6  1.0000  0.9998  0.9998  0.9997
```

Comment: Thanks, Data may not be boolean, would it work ..? and could you please provide some explanation to your code.

Comment: @user2458922 change to `s.mask(s==0)`

Comment: Thanks.. Is there a way to generalize, for example, this may only work when multiplication factor is 0.9999 instead if there if a function which does that ..And I could edit the function if required ?